# From multiple images selected for upload wrong image gets thumbnailed

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Have a form here with bunch of input **text** fields and a **file upload** input that can only accept **multiple images**.

**What needs to happen:**

After selecting a bunch of images and clicking **Submit** button - the controller should insert the text data into one table, then upload all the images and add their file names to the **images** table with foreign_key linking to the text data that was inserted, and finally make the first image, that was selected, turned into a thumbnail and upload its name and foreign_key linking to the text data row into **thumbnails** table too.

**What happens:**

Images+thumbnail get uploaded properly(or put into the upload folder without any duplicates and etc.), but for some reason the **last** image that was selected gets thumbnailed, not the first one.

Also, although only **one** image is thumbnailed - the database ends up adding name of every image, that were selected/uploaded, to the thumbnails table with `_thumb` in their names.

**crud.php** *(controller)*

```
function add()
        {
            //Set validation properties
            $this->_set_fields();

            //Set common properties
            $data['title'] = 'Add new data row';
            $data['message'] = '';
            $data['action'] = site_url('crud/addDataRow');
            $data['link_back'] = anchor('crud/index', 'Back to list', array('class' => 'back'));

            //Load the view
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/crud_edit', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        function addDataRow()
        {
            //Set common properties
            $data['title'] = 'Add new data row';
            $data['action'] = site_url('crud/addDataRow');
            $data['link_back'] = anchor('crud/index/', 'Back to list', array('class' => 'back'));

            //Set validation properties
            $this->_set_fields();
            $this->_set_rules();

            //Run validation
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $data['message'] = '';
            }
            else
            {
                //Get the text data from $_POST
                $data_row = array(
                    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                    'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
                    'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
                    'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                    'type' => $this->input->post('type')
                );

                //Insert text data into table
                $id = $this->crud_model->save($data_row);

                //Now move on to image processing
                //original image upload settings
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '6000';
                $config['max_width']  = '1680';
                $config['max_height']  = '1050';
                $path_to_uploads= './assets/upload';
                $config['upload_path'] = $path_to_uploads;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                $arr_files = @$_FILES['images'];

                $_FILES = array();
                foreach(array_keys($arr_files['name']) as $h){
                    $_FILES["file_{$h}"] = array(
                        'name' => $arr_files['name'][$h],
                        'type' => $arr_files['type'][$h],
                        'tmp_name' => $arr_files['tmp_name'][$h],
                        'error' => $arr_files['error'][$h],
                        'size' => $arr_files['size'][$h]
                    );
                }

                //add this
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                foreach(array_keys($_FILES) as $h) {

                    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($h)){
                        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                        //echo "<script>alert($error);</script>";
                        print($error); die;
                    }else{

                        $upload_data=$this->upload->data();
                        $file_name=$upload_data['file_name'];
                        $full_file_path = $path_to_uploads.'/'.$file_name;

                        $image_row = array(
                        'id_path' => $file_name,
                        'id_data_row' => $id
                        );

                        //Upload original image
                        $this->crud_model->save_image($image_row);

                        if(current($_FILES) == $_FILES['file_0']){
                            //Thumbnail config
                            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                            $config['source_image'] = $full_file_path;
                            $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                            $config['width'] = 150;
                            $config['height'] = 150;

                            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

                            $this->image_lib->resize();

                            $thumbnail_row = array(
                            'id_path' => str_replace(".", "_thumb.", $file_name),
                            'id_data_row' => $id
                            );

                            $this->crud_model->save_thumbnail($thumbnail_row);
                        }       
                    }
                }
                //Set form input name="id"
                $this->form_validation->id = $id;

                //Set user message
                $data['message'] = '<div class="success">New data row added!</div>';
            }

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/crud_edit', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

**crud_model.php** *(model)*

```
//Add new data row
        function save($data)
        {

            $this->db->insert($this->tbl_data, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        //Add the original image
        function save_image($data)
        {
            $this->db->insert($this->tbl_images, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        //Add the thumbnail upload path and id of the row in data table to link them
        function save_thumbnail($data)
        {
            $this->db->insert($this->tbl_thumbnails, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your check is failing so the loop is running all the way through each time and overwriting the thumbnail with the last image looped.

Try changing your check from

```
if(current($_FILES) == $_FILES['file_0']){
```

to

```
if($h=='file_0'){
```

Comment: Still thumbnails the wrong image, but does add new row to thumbnails table properly.

Comment: I just noticed that no matter what image I select first for upload to be thumbnailed - the upload input puts first image path based on their order of listing in the folder. Any way to counter that so that only the first image I selected is thumbnailed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The input reorders based on the order they are in on the computer you are uploading from? If so, hard to say without seeing the UI. I suppose you can create a separate input for thumbnail image. Or you can try giving the first image selected a different name with js...

Comment: I'll just create a separate input then. Thanks.